# The "->" Notation in linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

What does the "->" notation mean in Linux .

eg. When I do ls -l in a particular folder, I get the following.

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     29 Feb 27 12:23 ojdbc.jar -> /apps/hadoop/sqoop/ojdbc6.jar
```

Is the first file a placeholder of the second one?

Kind Regards.

Comment: It's a symbolic link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command "ls -l" uses "->" to denote a symbolic-link (that is, a psuedo-file which only points to another file).

In your example ojdbc.jar is a symbolic-link to /apps/hadoop/sqoop/ojdbc6.jar.

I'm not aware that this meaning holds beyond ls, however.

Answer (score 4):

It means the file is not a physical file, but a symbolic link pointing to the file to the right of the arrow.

Comment: You could compare them to Windows' shortcuts.